# How to save csv data as excel file using pyqt5

Tags: python, excel, csv

I have a problem while saving a CSV file to excel in the below function. Like after creating a excel file, when try to open it showing error like file format or file extension is not vaild

```
def writeCsv(self):
        # find empty cells
        for row in range(self.model.rowCount()):
            for column in range(self.model.columnCount()):
                myitem = self.model.item(row, column)
                if myitem is None:
                    item = QtGui.QStandardItem("")
                    self.model.setItem(row, column, item)
        fileName, _ = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self, "Save File",
                                                            (
                                                                        QtCore.QDir.homePath() + "/Dokumente/CSV/" + self.fname + ".xlsx"),
                                                            "xlsx files(*.xlsx)")
        if fileName:
            print(fileName)
            f = open(fileName, 'w')
            with f:
                writer = csv.writer(f,dialect= 'excel', delimiter = '/t')
                for rowNumber in range(self.model.rowCount()):
                    fields = [self.model.data(self.model.index(rowNumber, columnNumber),
                                              QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole)
                              for columnNumber in range(self.model.columnCount())]
                    writer.writerow(fields)
                self.fname = os.path.splitext(str(fileName))[0].split("/")[-1]
                self.setWindowTitle(self.fname)
                self.isChanged = False
```

Comment: Maybe take a look at what a [mre] is. Posting whole code here, is not good idea... And _I have a problem while saving a CSV file to excel_ doesn't match with, tags used in question. Probably [tag:csv] would be more relevant to your question.

Comment: use a library. https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ or pandas.